# How to connect in a spring boot project, an artifact developed in python in azure devops

Tags: python, java, spring-boot, azure-devops, artifacts

I am trying to integrate in my spring boot project, an artifact developed in python using azure devops and maven.
At the moment of selecting my artifact, in the "connection feed" section I indicate that I want to do it with maven, where it gives me the steps to integrate in my pom.xml the following:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/m2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </releases>

        <repository>
            <id>id-name</id>
            <url>url-package-devops</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </releases>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        </repository>
            <id>id-name</id>
            <url>url-package-devops</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>.
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Then, I use the mvn install command, it seems to install the artifact in my project but I can't see it, or I don't know where it is.
How could I download it and use it in some .java file?

To complement my comment, I add you the screenshots from this reply.

Here is my artifact from azure devops:
[Artifact from azure devops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy9ng.png)

If I click on "Connect to feed" and select "Maven" it gives me the options you explained in your answer, so that artifact is downloaded as usual.
[Connect to feed in maven](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQo3C.png)

In fact in the .m2 path I can already visualize it, but I don't know how I can use it inside my spring boot / JAVA project, since I don't know how to call it when importing.

That really is my doubt, how can I use this package that in spite of being developed in python, I can include it in my java project and use it at the moment of importing and consulting all its methods.
[package in .m2 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhlAs.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you published a package to Azure Artifact, and now you want to consume it and know where the package has been downloaded. Please correct me if I misunderstand.

For Maven packages, we cannot manually download them directly from the UI. However, we can set the target package as the dependency of our project and then install it.

To consume a package in Azure Artifact, go to your package in the feed.  [Connect your project to your feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops#set-up-authentication) firstly. Then add the dependency to your `pom.xml` file.
[image]

Go to your project's root folder and run `mvn install`, then the dependencies will be downloaded to your local repository. Maven maintains a repository of dependencies on your local machine (usually in a .m2/repository directory in your home directory) for quick access to project dependencies. For me it is "C:\Users\Administrator.m2". And I can see my target package as shown below after installing:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my friend. Yes, exactly what you said is what I need to do. Actually, I already have my package in the path C:\UsersUser.m2repository\example\combitcoincore

But that's where my doubt is, in the azure devops environment where my artifact is, if I click on "Connect to Feed" it allows me different options to connect, for example with Nuget, npm, maven, etc. Is it possible to use that package developed in python in a spring boot project without any problem? Since I am using the maven feed, or there must be some other particularities to integrate it.

Comment: Azure Artifact feed itself has no type. It is used to store different types of packages( NuGet, npm, Python, Maven, Cargo, and Universal Packages.) I'm not an expert on the Spring Boot project. According to my investigation, Spring Boot is a Java-based framework. But your package is developed for python. Java and Python are two different programming languages that run on different virtual machines. I'm afraid you can't reference a python-based package in a Java project.